Implement FromStr for structs with fields such as Option<T> or Vec<T> using procedural macros in Rust
I need some help with procedural macros using derive. I'm trying to implement FromStr for struct fields using the macro. If I have fields with data types such as Vec<T> (T as in using the macro) and for Option<T>. But I have no clue how that can be properly done to handle different structs with different fields (it can be different). This is how far I've come so far:
my_project/src/main.rs
#[derive(MyCustomMacro)]
pub struct Product {
    id: usize,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    price: f64,
    stock_quantity: usize,
    category: Category,
    related: Vec<Product>,
    discount: Option<f64>,
}

my_derive/src/lib.rs
#[proc_macro_derive(MyCustomMacro)]
pub fn my_derive_func(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
  let cloned_input = input.clone();
  let derive_input: DeriveInput = parse_macro_input!(cloned_input);
  let DeriveInput {
          ident, data, attrs, ..
  } = derive_input.clone();
  
  let mut from_str_impl = TokenStream2::default();
  
  if let syn::Data::Struct(s) = data {
    if let syn::Fields::Named(FieldsNamed { named, .. }) = s.fields {
  
    // Implement the std::str::FromStr trait
    from_str_impl.extend(quote! {
        impl std::str::FromStr for #ident {
            type Err = std::string::ParseError;
    
            fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
                // How can I handle all of this?
            }
        }
    }); // from_str_impl

This is an error I'm getting:
the trait `FromStr` is not implemented for `Option<f64>`

The desired outcome (I believe) should be:
Ok(Product { 
        id: 1,
        name: "Some Name",
        description: "Some Description",
        price: 20.0,
        stock_quantity: 0,
        category: Category { id: 0, name: "Some Name" },
        related: vec![ Category { id: 1, name: "Some Name" }, Category { id: 2, name: "Some Other Name" }],
        discount: 10.0 // or None
})


This sounds like you really want serde deserialization, not FromStr.

How so @cdhowie and how would I go about to do that? I'm pretty new to Rust. I want to avoid bringing in as few dependencies as possible since I'm creating a library.

I'm not even sure it works inside the .extend() call to use libraries since it's generating code? I think I tried it before and it complained about that part.

Note that macros cannot reliably detect types.

@MarcusCvjeticanin Basically what I'm saying is that you're implementing FromStr on the struct but it's not clear to me how you intend to parse each distinct field from the input. Is it JSON, CSV, something else?
